# Передача данных с Класса в ViewController UILable

Tags: swift

Доброе время суток! Я новичок в Swift, мне нужно передать данные с одного класса в `VIewController UILable`, к которому подключён `StoryBoard`. Пытался сделать так:

```
class AppEngine: NSObject

     var myViewController = ViewController()
    myViewController.setLabelText(txtValue: (linesABC?[iSpeakerCount])!)

class ViewController: UIViewController

    func setLabelText(txtValue: String){
    labelText.text? = txtValue //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

}
```

Передача данных в `ViewController` для присвоения их к `UILable` текст, но `UILable` почему-тo иcчез как будто. Может ли кто поставить меня на верный путь?

Comment: Ошибка подчеркивает сам labelText

Comment: Вам помогут паттерны delegate, notification и callbacks.